# Auto link the urls in page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to auto link the URLs in a page.

For example

This is a html content and contains text url www.example.com and linked url <a href='www.example.com'> example </a>. It might followed by http like [http://www.example.com]

I need the result to be like this:

This is a html content and contains text url http://www.example.com and linked url http://www.example.com. It might followed by http like http://www.example.com

I have used below function but its not working with the url which starting with www.

```
    jQuery.fn.autolink = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
            var re = /((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-\{\}$!|]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g;
            $J(this).html($J(this).html().replace(re, '$1 '));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried already something or you just don't know how to start?

Comment: @roXon Yes. i have tried with regex but i could not get correct solutions.I have updated my question with the jquery function

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This will modify the href attribute and the html of hyperlink.

```
$("a").each(function(k,v){
   this.attr("href","http://"+this.attr("href"));
   this.html("http://www."+this.html()+".com");
})
```

Comment: not quite. OP is asking how to recognize any kind of URLs from the page content and transform them into "real" links.

Comment: @Fahim I need to find the url in a HTML content.It might contains palin text url as well as formatted anchor tags.So i need to link the plain text url's only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function and pass your anchor tag text url as urlname and href as linkname

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(urlname, linkname) {

if (linkname && !linkname.match(/^http([s]?):\/\/.*/)) {
    linkname = 'http://' + linkname
}
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i;
return linkname.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>"+urlname+"</a>");
```

}